# Vaadin Flow 14 Can't move a node from one state tree to another error when refreshing

Tags: java, vaadin, refresh, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

i have a problem with adding again btn to layout after this layout is cleared from components. I'm gettin a error

> Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree

for the line

```
            actionsLay.add(testButton);
```

after refreshing few times, and i don't get it why this error is showing. Below is very simple code to show this error when i'm adding and removing button for refresh action. In my app it is much more complicated code and i'm getting this error aswell after some page refresh and only for one component. I know that i can just add

```
testButton.getElement().removeFromTree()
```

but until I know why this error appears then I won't know when when i should add this line.

I'm using Vaadin 14.8.14.

```
@Route(value = "test")
@UIScope
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class testPanel extends Div {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5081824598131333345L;

    Button testButton;
    private HorizontalLayout actionsLay;
    private boolean addBtn = true;
    public testPanel() {
        testButton = new Button(new Icon(VaadinIcon.REFRESH));
        actionsLay = new HorizontalLayout();
        add(actionsLay);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        if (addBtn) {
            actionsLay.removeAll();
            actionsLay.add(testButton);
            addBtn = false;
        } else {
            actionsLay.removeAll();
            addBtn = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The error is thrown becouse

```
isOwnerAttached = ((StateTree) getOwner()).getRootNode()
                .isAttached();
```

in class StateNode in method doSetTree is true.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you see is there to guard against accidentally reusing the same component instance between separate UIs e.g. by using the component instance through a singleton bean with Spring or CDI.

Because `@PreserveOnRefresh` is technically creating a new UI when you refresh, there's some special logic that goes through components that are attached during the refresh and detaches them from the old UI in a special way (`removeFromTree()`) to avoid triggering the logic that prevents accidental sharing.

I suspect the problem in your case is that the button isn't always attached when the refresh happens, which also means that it doesn't get detached in that special way. This means that you need to use `removeFromTree()` for whenever you want to be able to reuse something that wasn't attached when the refresh happened.

Comment: Shouldn't it be by default that when i use removeAll() then it should use removeFromTree()  for each child to be sure that next adding will be without error? what is the point of not doing it every time?

Comment: In my example button should be always in one UI because after i'm removing it from layout then it should't be in any UI so when i'm adding it again to the new UI of the layout then it isn't in any older UI.

Comment: I added button which on click is executing same code as onattach and then there is no error when i'm reloading browser tab with component attached or detached. Do i dont think that the problem is that component isnt detached on special way. There is sole problem with doing it im attache listener.

Comment: Does indeed seem like my assumption was mistaken. Good that you investigated further and also good that you filed this as an issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/15642

Comment: For the record, removeAll() shouldn't do removeFromTree() since removeAll() is also what's used behind the scenes if an instance is accidentally shared because of too wide scopes.